# Arranging objects under master template objects in Adobe Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design

I have set up an Adobe Indesign template and it is working perfectly okay except that I can't arrange page objects under the objects that come from the master template. I tried send it to back from arrange option but this doesn't seem to be the solution. Is there any way to do this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override Master Page items in InDesign, simply <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+Click the item you wish to make editable on the page (override).

Then, in your Layers Panel, you can rearrange the stacking order of the items.

You can also override every Master Page item on the page by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+Clicking on your current page in the Pages Panel and selecting Override All Master Page Items.

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+clicking the item from master template and bringing it to the front from 'Arrange' option worked.

Answer (score 2):

In cases like these, it's wise to create several layers and arrange the master page items oon those layers.

By default, a master page item is on the very bottom *of its respective layer*. So, if you have, for example, three layers, named 'top', 'middle' and 'bottom', you should put your blue bar master page item on the 'top' layer and have your (regular) yellow item on the regular page's layer 'middle' or 'bottom'.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else gets confused like me even with the help of the approved answer + reply from OP.. I had the exact same problem as OP. Their instructions just wasn't clear to me and it took a while to get it.

Note: I'm using Windows.

CTRL + SHIFT + LEFT click on the Master Element on the specific page you want to edit (not the Master Page window).

Then go to OBJECT in the top left corner, and select ARRANGE. Click on 'BRING TO FRONT'. I'm still new to InDesign so yeah haha